# Got error in build Makefile with terminal into Mac

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin, makefile, binding

I want to create Fat binary using **Makefile**.

For that I create one makefile and try to build using terminal.

I got error

> "*** missing seperator. Stop"

### Here is my Makefile

```
XBUILD=/Applicaitons/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild
PROJECT_ROOT=./MTSCRADemo
PROJECT=$(PROJECT_ROOT)/MTSCRADemo.xcodeproj
TARGET=MTSCRADemo

all:    lib$(TARGET).a

lib$(TARGET)-i386.a:    $(XBUILD)   -project    $(PROJECT)  -target $(TARGET)   -sdk    iphonesimulator -configuration  Release clean   build   -mv $(PROJECT_ROOT)/build/Release-iphonesimulator/lib$(TARGET).a    $@

lib$(TARGET)-armv7.a:   $(XBUILD)   -project    $(PROJECT)  -target $(TARGET)   -sdk    iphoneos    -arch   armv7   -configuration  Release clean   build   -mv $(PROJECT_ROOT)/build/Release-iphones/lib$(TARGET).a    $@

lib$(TARGET)-arm64.a:   $(XBUILD)   -project    $(PROJECT)  -target $(TARGET)   -sdk    iphoneos    -arch   arm64   -configuration  Release clean   build   -mv $(PROJECT_ROOT)/build/Release-iphoneos/lib$(TARGET).a $@

lib$(TARGET)SDK.a:  lib$(TARGET)-i386.a lib$(TARGET)-arm7.a lib$(TARGET)-arm64.a
    xcrun   -sdk iphoneos   lipo    -create -output $@  $^

clean:  -rm -f  *.a *.dll
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Errors in make file : \*\*\* missing separator. Stop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576237/errors-in-make-file-missing-separator-stop)

Answer (score 0):

I think this may already have an answer here:
[Errors in make file : *** missing separator. Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576237/errors-in-make-file-missing-separator-stop)

You need a tab before all of the lines after `all:` I believe.