# Makefile - Missing separator. Stop

Tags: makefile

When trying to run the command make, I am getting the error:
makefile:22: *** missing separator.  Stop.
Line 22 would be the line just before g++ driver.o ground.o...
I know I need to use tabs, instead of spaces, but it still does not work.
Any idea? This is my code:

```
LFLAGS = -lglut -lGLU -lGL

a.out:  driver.o ground.o game.o uiInteract.o uiDraw.o point.o lander.o velocity.o 
 g++ driver.o ground.o game.o uiInteract.o uiDraw.o point.o lander.o velocity.o $(LFLAGS)
 tar -j -cf moonLander.tar makefile *.h *.cpp

uiDraw.o: uiDraw.cpp uiDraw.h
 g++ -c uiDraw.cpp

uiInteract.o: uiInteract.cpp uiInteract.h
 g++ -c uiInteract.cpp

point.o: point.cpp point.h
 g++ -c point.cpp

ground.o: ground.cpp ground.h
 g++ -c ground.cpp

game.o: game.h game.cpp uiDraw.h uiInteract.h point.h ground.h
 g++ -c game.cpp

driver.o: driver.cpp game.h uiInteract.h
 g++ -c driver.cpp

lander.o: lander.cpp lander.h point.h velocity.h uiDraw.h
 g++ -c: lander.cpp

velocity.o: velocity.cpp velocity.h
 g++ -c: velocity.cpp

clean:
 rm a.out *.o *.tar
```

Comment: i dont know how to mark the thread as duplicate so im just going to comment this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936337/makefile1-missing-separator-stop

Comment: Thank you very much, I fixed it, it was a text editor problem.

Comment: PROBLEM: Makefile requires a "tab".  SOLUTION: the link Lorence Hernandez cited: [Makefile:1: *** missing separator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936337/makefile1-missing-separator-stop).  Will "close/duplicate".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931770/makefile4-missing-separator-stop you can resolve your error from here

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, but this appears to be a duplicate of [Errors in make file : *** missing separator. Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576237/errors-in-make-file-missing-separator-stop)
Depending on the editor you are using (and how you've configured that editor), your tabs might be getting replaced with spaces (i.e, when you hit the tab key, it inputs 4 spaces instead).
Either change your editor to use tab characters instead of spaces, or use another editor that is set up that way.